# opencv otsu binarization not working

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I tried to apply opencv OTSU binarization on the following image, but it generate a black image.

[image]

Here is the following python code:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('test_otsu.png', 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0,250,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite('temp.png', thresh)
```

Did I miss anything in my code? Please help me how to get correct binarization of the given image.

Comment: it seems a wrong threshold is determined, can you try manual binerization?

Answer (score 2):

the problems seems to be with the white border of the image you are using. remove it manually and test again.